# Unable to add tables in the empty database in visual studio ultimate 2012 using graphic user interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I just want to make a very simple database in microsoft visual studio.

What I did?
1. I created new project in C# as WindowsFormApplication (created default code, I didn't change it, because I am interested in making the database only, so no source code).
2. Then on the Solution Explorer Panel of Visual Studio, I right clicked on the application and clicked on Add -> New Item.
3. Then I selected Service Database.
4. The database is created.
5. I go to server explorer and expand the database and tabled, then i see there is no table.
6. I right click on tables and then I click add new table and I get this error
"Object reference is not set to instance of an object"

There are plenty of answers for this error on stack overflow and other sites but nothing helped me.

I reinstalled Management Objects and Compact 4.0 ...  still nothing.

My OS is windows 7. 64 bit operating system.
Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

I really need to make a test database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled the disabled services from task manager and then reinstalled everything and worked fine.